# C++ Syntax and compiler error - no match for operator<<

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++14

new to C++ coding and was trying to get a hand of unique pointers. I'm running into 3 errors

> ```
> 1.cpp|14|error: no match for 'operator<<'
>
> 2.cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<char>' lvalue to std::basic_ostream<char>&&
> ```

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <memory>


 using std::cout;
 using std::cin;
 using std::endl;

 using std::make_unique;

 int main (){

 auto ptr = make_unique<int>(4);

 cout << "The value of ptr: " << ptr << endl;

 cout << "The value of ptr: " << &ptr;

}
```

Comment: You need to dereference `ptr`: `cout << "The value of ptr: " << *ptr << endl;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ptr` is `std::unique_ptr<int>`, and you have no definition of `operator <<(std::ostream&, std::unique_ptr<int>)`, this is why you get an error when compiling your code.

The `unique_ptr` is just a wrapper around a raw pointer. To get the actual pointer (the one which is being wrapped), just call `get()`, in this case it will return an `int*`, and you can print it without defining any other function or overloading any operator. To get the value being pointed by `ptr`, just dereference it like normal pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main () {
  auto ptr = std::make_unique<int>(4);
  std::cout << "The value ptr is pointing: " << *ptr << '\n' // Dereference the pointer
      << "The value of ptr: " << ptr.get() << std::endl; // Get the actual pointer
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many syntax error in this code so below is correct program that you can try :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
int main()
{


using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;

using std::make_unique;

auto ptr = make_unique<int>(4);

//there is no overload of ostream operator for std::unique_ptr
//so you can't directly do << ptr
cout << "The value of ptr: " << *ptr << endl; 
//& will print address not value
cout << "The Address of ptr: " << &ptr;


}
```

Comment: Adding explanations would be better.

Comment: `cout << "The Address of ptr: " << &ptr;` prints the address of the `unique_ptr`, not the `int` pointed at by the `unique_ptr`. You want `ptr.get()`